# WebApi OData v3 Expand with EF 6 Lazy Load Disabled

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have disabled lazy load from my DbContext

```
base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

When I use OData v3 $expand parameter, Company object isn't get filled.

> http://localhost:36983/odata/Projects?$top=10&$skip=0&$expand=Company&$inlinecount=allpages

If I Enable lazy load, it get filled.

But I dont want to set Include on ProjectController like:

```
[EnableQuery]
public PageResult<Project> GetProjects()
{
    return new PageResult<Project>(db.Project.Include("Company"));
}
```

This could be a Bug Issue of WebApi OData v3?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a bug.

I really have to Include nested objects.

Thank you.